# How to store data across multiple platforms in an Apache Cordova app with Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create an Apache Cordova App designed for iOS and Android. I am looking for a way to store data through a web or cloud-based database so everyone that has the app downloaded can push and pull information from one source.

I've looked into the Web SQL Plugin for Visual Studio but its only designed for Windows and Windows Phone.

Specifically i am looking to add a very simple message board where one user can comment and a different user can see that comment on their own phone.

What plugin or method call for visual studio can i use so that i am able to store data in either a key,value format or in a table format, keeping in mind that the data needs to be accessible across many devices and 2 platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: Dustin, take a look at Firebase. I think it will provide the functionality you're looking for. It's a good start and easy to setup, manage, etc.  Here are some links:  [FireBase URL](https://www.firebase.com/)      [Example Code using Firebase](https://github.com/Microsoft/ngconf2015demo)    [Local Version I created for VS2015](https://github.com/dbiele/ngconf2015demo_local)

Comment: Thanks so much it works perfectly.  I can't give you credit fro your answer because you answered it in a comment but i really appreciate the help.